# Can we run ios release build on simulators for Automated tests

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator, detox

I tried to run the release build app in Simulator, but it is being crashed after opening. After some exploration, I came to know that we can't run release build which is built for the device on iOS Simulator

Here my use case is that I want to run automated tests without building two times (One is for Simulator, Another one is for Actual device ) in CI as it will take double the time to get the build to succeed.

So I want to know whether there is any solution where I can build only once and test it in the simulator and distribute it.

Comment: Not really, because the devices have different processors. Simulator builds are x86 while device builds are ARM. If you upload a binary that contains both x86 and ARM builds, it will be rejected by App Store Connect.  In theory, you could create a build with all architectures and then strip the x86 before uploading to App Store Connect,  but is your build time really that long?

Comment: Thank you . @Paulw11 Yeah Unfortunately build it is taking 39 mins in CI without E2E tests for iOS. And I am curious to know what is the average time of builds for react native apps. Is my build time is too high ?